# How to fix problem with not working updateServing function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I'm trying to implement a function which would calculate the servings for the ingredients from my website.

That function is in Recipe.js file and looks like that:

```
    updateServings(type) {
        // Servings
        const newServings = type === 'dec' ? this.servings - 1 : this.servings + 1;

        // Ingredients
        this.ingredients.forEach((ingr) => {
        ingr.count = this.capDecimal(ingr.count * (newServings / this.servings));
        });
        this.servings = newServings;
       }
```

The problem is that when I console.log(state.recipe); in index.js this event Listener works, it will console log state.recipe after clicking - or + button on the website but it wont change the amount of serving in the recipe object:

```
elements.recipe.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.matches('.btn-decrease .btn-decrease *')){
        //Decrease button is clicked
        if(state.recipe.servings > 1){
            state.recipe.updateServings('dec'); 
        } 
    }else if(e.target.matches('.btn-increase .btn-increase *')){
        //Increase button was clicked
        state.recipe.updateServings('inc'); 

    }
    console.log(state.recipe);
});
```

I clicked 2 times but property serving still says 4 like here:

https://forum.toshitimes.com/uploads/toshitimes/original/2X/6/6bada9081879db1a14df9bad010382606fda253f.png

It a bigger project so I believe I need to include the whole repository from github: https://github.com/damianjnc/forkifyApp.git

What I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the view after the click event

```
elements.recipe.addEventListener('click', e => {
//....
 try {
    recipeView.clearRecipe();
    recipeView.renderRecipe(state.recipe);
  } catch (error) {
      alert('error processing the recipe:(');
  }

});
```

note: you need to declare your class properties

```
export default class Recipe {
    ingredients;
    servings;
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

and you need map instead of forEach

```
this.ingredients = this.ingredients.map((ingr) => {
        ingr.count = this.capDecimal(ingr.count * (newServings / this.servings));
        return ingr;
});
```